# C++11: return_type (for std::bind) of functor where return type is based on input type

Tags: c++, c++11, std, boost-bind

I'm playing with functor composition, where the return type of a functor depends on the input type:

```
template<typename V>
class F
{
protected:
    V v_;
public:
    using return_type = ?;

    F(V v) : v_(v) {}

    template<typename T>
    typename T::U operator()(T t)
    {
        v.method(t);
    }
};

...

X x;
Y y;
F<X> f(x);
F<Y> g(y);
auto h = std::bind(f, std::bind(g, _1));
h(...);  // problem is here :(
```

Is it possible to find `return_type` using `decltype` so that `std::bind` will work? If so, how?

**Edit**: I replace `U<T>` with `typename T::U` because the return type depends on the type. I hope this is clearer now.

**Edit 2 (4?)**: Added a compilable example that reproduces the problem.

```
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;

template<typename I>
struct R
{
    using IT = I;
    R(I x, I y) : b(x), e(y) {}
    I b;
    I e;
};

template<typename IN, typename II>
class CI
{
    CI(II i) {}
};

template<typename IN>
class C
{
    template<typename IR>
    R<CI<IN, typename IR::IT> >
    operator()(IR& i)
    {
        return R<CI<IN, typename IR::IT> >(
            CI<IN, typename IR::IT>(i.b),
            CI<IN, typename IR::IT>(i.e));
    }
};

struct F {};
struct G {};
struct H {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    C<F> a;
    C<G> b;
    auto c = std::bind(a, std::bind(b, _1));
    R<H> r{H{}, H{}};
    c(r);
}
```

Comment: You use, but do not define, `U`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Doesn't `bind` use `result_of`, and hence `decltype`, anyway and so you don't even need `return_type`?

Comment: `U<T>` was just an example of a return type that depended on the input type. I replaced it with `typename T::U` to make it clearer.

Comment: So you have an arbitrary number of input types, giving rise to an arbitrary number of output types, and you want to typedef a single output type? I don't think it can work like this. Either require your `T::U`s be convertible to some common type, or parameterize the whole functor on `T`.

Comment: Originally, the whole functor was parametrized on `T` - but that would make it impossible to create a generic functor. The requirement of `T::U` be convertible to some common type might work, though.

Comment: std::bind will work, @KerrekSB, but when I try to call the resulting function I get `no matching function for call to object of type` and `candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Result'`.

Comment: OK, I'm looking at this in more detail now. An obvious problem occurs, in that `bind(g, _1)` doesn't make sense: `g` doesn't have a simple member function `operator()(T)`, so there's no way for the bind expression to resolve even the function call itself statically. You really need a *templated* wrapper for the `bind` call.

Comment: A _templated_ wrapper, @KerrekSB? As in `std::bind<T>(...)`?

Comment: More like in `bind_wrapper<R, T> { typedef std::function<R(T)> type; type f; /* ... */ };` and a suitable constructor that makes the correct cast+bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about using `std::bind` for a minute and just try the direct approach:

```
C<F> a;
C<G> b;
R<H> r{H{}, H{}};
a(b(r));
```

This won't even compile, so there's no way the `bind` version will!

`b(r)` isn't valid because of an access violation, and if you fix that `a(b(r))` fails because you try to bind a temporary to a non-const lvalue-reference

Comment: Correct! Thanks for showing me how to "fish" for future mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it! I had to replace `C::operator()(IR& i)` with `C::operator()(IR i)` because it was recursive. Maybe adding a `move` constructor to `IR` would help performance, but...? In fact, what happened was that `clang`'s errors weren't as helpful as `gcc`'s. Well, blame me.

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be solved using alternative function syntax:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct Number {
  T t_;
  Number(T t) : t_(t) {}
  T operator+(T t) { return t_ + t; }
};

struct F {
  template<typename T>
  auto operator()(T x) -> decltype(x + 1)
  {
    return x + 1;
  }
} f, g;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  auto h = std::bind(f, std::bind(g, _1));
  std::cout << h(Number<int>(1)) << std::endl;
}
```

and `value_type` is not needed here and it fact it provided problems as `int` returned from `g(_1)` will never have `int::value_type` inside expected by `f`.

Comment: @bruno nery Ohh, it seems you removed your concrete example :-( I hope my answer still helps...

Comment: I tried replacing my return type with auto, @Mateusz Pusz, but it didn't help. I'll try to find a contained concrete example :(.

Comment: Added a **real** concrete example, @Mateusz Pusz. Can you crack that one? :)